# Can someone explain me how to use NodeRT (Windows.Gaming.Input) module in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I'm trying to import Gamepad class from this module but i always get an error "Invalid arguments, no suitable constructor found"
This is my code:

```
const { Gamepad } = require('@nodert-win10-20h1/windows.gaming.input')

const gamepad = new Gamepad()
```

If i'm trying to console.log **Gamepad** i got this in console:

```
Gamepad [Function: Gamepad] {
  castFrom: [Function: castFrom],
  fromGameController: [Function: fromGameController],
  gamepads: Windows::Foundation::Collections:IVectorView {
    __winRtInstance__: true
  }
}
```

where Gamepad is a function.

Maybe someone can give me a link to documentation for this module or explain me how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nodert-win10-20h1/windows.gaming.input), I can read that:

> The API exposed by this module is (almost) the same as the API that is
> listed in:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Windows.Gaming.Input.aspx

And in the API you can read:

> Instances of the Gamepad class cannot be created directly; instead,
> instances of the Gamepad class are retrieved through the
> Gamepad.Gamepads property listing all connected gamepads or through
> the Gamepad.GamepadAdded event.

So I think that the use should be (very very roughly) :

```
const { Gamepad } = require('@nodert-win10-20h1/windows.gaming.input');
const firstGamePad = GamePad.gamepads.IndexOf(0); //retrieve the first GP found
let currentInput = firstGamePad.GetCurrentReading();// or something like this, just check firstGamePad properties
```

Comment: I know :) but looks like i get something like TypeScript templates if i use this package like that. I always get Gamepad.Gamepads(0) is not a function

Comment: @cikpak It seems that IVectorView has IndexOf() to retrieve the elements. Answer edited. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivectorview-1?view=winrt-19041